# Clause construction

Tags: clauses

1. I read the book in my home yesterday that you gave me last month.
2. The book that you gave me last month I read in my home yesterday.
3. I read in my home yesterday the book that you gave me last month.

Which one sentence above is correct.

Comment: It might be easier for us to help if we knew how you were thinking about this problem. Have you any rules for putting together complex sentences like this? Which of the three seems good to you?

Answer (score 2):

I say none of the sentences are good to use and instead present you with the *hidden* fourth option.

> Yesterday in my home, I read the book that you gave me last month.

By clumping together the propositional phrase (in my home) and the adverb (yesterday) into a dependent clause, you make the sentence significantly easier to read and understand.